# How to append data sets when there is an overlap in data?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have two data sets and they both have the same column names. One of the data sets is an excel file and contains historical data up until April. The second data set is linked to a database but will only ever contain 6 rolling months' worth of data. How would I go about appending the two data sets, by ensuring that duplicates are removed? Basically, I'd like to prioritise the data from the live source, but also ensure that the data doesn't get lost.

My concern is: what will happen to May data in 14 months from now, since it is not in the current excel data set, and it will not be in the live data set? How do I ensure that May data doesn't disappear in 14 months' time?

Answer (score 1):

Power Query does not support historical data. If you want to preserve this data you must implement some solution that stores the rolling data so it doesn’t «roll off», so to speak.